# Partition configuration for dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7 in separate partition

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

**Partitions:**

```
MBR                 100 MB  (Primary)
C: Windows 7        100 GB  (Primary)
D:                  35 GB   (Logical)
E:                  280 GB  (Logical)
Unallocated         50 GB   (free)
```

I want this unallocated space of 50 GB to be used for Ubuntu Now that Ubuntu require at least two partitions to function correctly:

```
root
swap
```

But MBR doesn't allow more than 4 primary(including extended) partitions in a disk.

Is this time for me to change my partition table to GPT (meaning that I would have to switch from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1). Would I be able to do that? Isn't GPT hardware dependent?

---

**Additional Details:**

I used GParted tool from ubuntu to create GPT partition table using a USB bootable version of Ubuntu. After that when I tried creating more partitions with windows 8.1 installation in the same disk it generates an error saying [We couldn't create a new partition Error Code: 0xeacbbf40] although it shows my previous configuration of partitions(created with GParted).

Also, when doing reverse of this i.e. Creating GPT partition table from "diskpart" tool from windows command prompt it creates successfully which then is then considered misconfigured partition table from GParted (GParted won't even read the current partition schema, just shows huge unallocated space).

And yes, my laptop ([Acer Aspire V3-551G](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1290802/acer-aspire-v3-551g-84504g50makk-notebook.html)) is 3 years old and it came up with Windows 7 pre-installed.

Comment: You have 2 primary partitions and want to add 2 more. If 4 is the max, what's the problem?

Comment: @jiggunjer 2 primary partitions 1 extended partition and want 2 more making it a total of "5" while only 4 partitions can be created in MBR.

Comment: you said 4 primary is the limit, so why count the extended? Also im not sure the swap needs a primary partition.

Comment: Well, the count includes the extended ones too!!
@jiggunjer with linuxdev2013's answer and some research I can now conclude that ONLY windows need to be installed in primary partitions, while Linux CAN be installed in logical partitions as well as primary partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ n0noob,   While GPT is highly recommended for ease and "future proofing" your install you can still use MBR.  Windows 8/8.1 migration IS **NOT** Required in either of the following setups..

Gonna make the following assumptions:

-- Laptop is at least 4 years old OR newer  which means it is EFI capable

-- Not all of Drives D:\ and/or E:\ are full ---or are backed up properly..

-- A ubuntu And / or Windows installer Media are handy or obtainable.

---

- TO retain MBR: Assuming some or all of D:\ or E:\ are free

  ---

On a Windows Or Ubuntu Installer

1) Boot to the formatter screen

2) "grow E:\ (and any portion of D:\ that is free) to include the additional space making it an extended Partition --with at least "logical" volumes -- (for ex. 280 Gb + 50 Gb = 330 Gb for the "New E:) second one will be Ubuntu

3) Reboot and get into Installer's boot repair tool and rebuild the BCD (Boot Code Directory)

3a)  After OR in place of  3)  you can now boot into Ubuntu  and use the space from E:\ to install the Ubuntu install using AT A minumum  /, /home, swap  (as separate  logicals inside  E:\ -- Ubuntu will call it /dev/sda3 - /dev/sda6  --the installer will handle the boot order just make sure when asked where it goes ---again assuming no new drives in the mix -- /dev/sda

---

- TO Migrate to GPT:

  ---

1) Backup anything worth it to you from Windows

2) Using the Formatter from either Windows OR Ubuntu  Wipe / delete / Format the drive and re-create a new table --GPT (Globally Universal Unique Identification Partition Table )

3) Create At a Minumum 4 partitions --all partitions are "Primary" on GPT  --also good as  you can boot from ANY of them if a valid install resides there.
 3a)

```
  Partition 1 ~ 40Mb  --biosboot (aka biosgrub) --this is needed as a overflow space for the UEFI loader -- If your current or future  motherboard has EFI  split this into  a 5Mb and 35Mb  scheme the 5Mb for biosgrub and the 35Gb  for  {/boot}/efi 

  Partition 2 ~ 35-40Gb (assuming sizes were backwards in post )  This will be the Windows Main Partition -- C:\

  Partition 3 ~ 100Gb  -- D:\ for whatever on Windows  OR possible a "share for both OSes 

  Partition 4 ~ Balance of the drive (assumes LVM for Ubuntu )

       Partition 4 (Logical -- /dev/sda4)  ~10-15Gb  /  for Ubuntu (the equal to C:\ )

       Partition 4 (Logical -- /dev/sda5)  ~2-4Gb  Swap  (assumes less than 8 Gb of  on-board RAM)

       Partition 4 (Logical -- /dev/sda6)  Balance of the Drive (~ 290gb)  /home (the equal to D:\)
```

AS with MBR schema Above this is how the Extended would look (the Partition 4 part would be the extended in a MBR world)

In both cases  make sure the Ubuntu Installer (for ease of  loader rebuilding  this should be last  --aka  install / fix Windows THEN install ubuntu

---

**NOTE:** There are tools like Gdisk and Gparted that can "In-place" Create a **"Hybrid"** Table these are

- Highly advanced techniques
- More more unstable and carry a much higher data loss potential..

Comment: Your answer is undoubtedly appreciable!! I have few doubts though!!
As per additional details I provided my laptop doesn't seem ready for GPT an EFI. I looked for EFI and Legacy modes of operation in BIOS configuration, checked BIOS mode in "msinfo32" utility in Windows 8.1.
What do you think?

Comment: Then it's Not the Motherboard OR tools BUT is the crappy MBR default of  the Win 7 installer  -- there are two workarounds install win 8 / 8.1  OR  (link pending)  using console in installer mode to create a gpt hybrid entry to get Win 7 installer to play nice...  If you wish to use GPT and keep win 7  I can have that link tonight when I get home and have time to search through my bookmarks for it..

Comment: I'd upvote if this was more than a cooking recipe. I.e. it lacks explanations/overview of the solutions.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 well, I erased that MBR created with my old Windows 7 and tried creating GPT partition table(provided details in the question) with both Windows 8.1 as well as GParted but was found to be incompatible with each other (for GPT only).

Comment: Which was incompatible ?

Comment: GPT created by GParted was not read properly by Windows 8.1 installer. Instead it overwrite the existing GPT with MBR partition table without even notifying me.

Comment: Anyways GPT doesn't seem to work with my laptop. Ubuntu in logical partitons (in MBR) is working for me (at least for now).